# How to get the name of the parent project in CMake?

Tags: cmake

Please see the below minimal example:

```
├───CMakeLists.txt
├───bar
│   ├───CMakeLists.txt
```

CMakeLists.txt

```
cmake_minimum_required(VERSION 3.20)
project(foo)
add_subdirectory(bar)
```

bar/CMakeLists.txt

```
project(bar)
cmake_path(GET CMAKE_CURRENT_LIST_DIR PARENT_PATH BAR_PARENT_DIR)
# how can I get `foo` given ${BAR_PARENT_DIR}?
# or is there a better way to get `foo`?
```

The real use case is that originally `foo` was extracted via `${CMAKE_PROJECT_NAME}`, but recently there's a need to make the repo submodule compatible. Once this repo is being used as a submodule,  `${CMAKE_PROJECT_NAME}` won't be equivalent to `foo` anymore. Additionally, `bar` is a submodule of `foo`, so we aren't allowed to hard code `foo` into bar/CMakeLists.txt because that would break other repos that are using `bar` as a submodule.

Is there a way to extract the project name of a CMakeLists.txt from a parent directory?

Edit: I am looking for a solution that will make the below scenario work. Meaning `foo` is submoduled by another project. e.g.

```
baz
├───CMakeLists.txt
├───foo
│   ├───CMakeLists.txt
│   ├───bar
│        ├───CMakeLists.txt
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> Yes, the project name of the immediate parent.

This is not so hard. The `project()` command *always* sets the `PROJECT_NAME` variable when it is called. So the value of that variable just before *you* call `project()` is the name of the immediate parent.

There's nothing standard for this, but it's trivial to implement:

```
cmake_minimum_required(VERSION 3.23)

set(PARENT_PROJECT_NAME "${PROJECT_NAME}")
project(bar)

if (PARENT_PROJECT_NAME)
  message(STATUS "Found parent: ${PARENT_PROJECT_NAME}")
else ()
  message(STATUS "No parent!")
endif ()
```

Comment: Like I said, when `foo` is submoduled, `${CMAKE_PROJECT_NAME}` won't be `foo` anymore. It will become `baz` as shown in my edit, but it needs to be `foo` in order to work.

Comment: @user3667089 - You want to get the project name not of the current project or the top-level project, but the immediate parent?

Comment: Yes, the project name of the immediate parent.

Comment: Oh, so it's in the `${PROJECT_NAME}` variable as long as it's called before `project(bar)` ... I thought `${PROJECT_NAME}` will be reset to empty for every new CMakeLists.txt. Thanks a lot for the answer.